# django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet. django 1.8

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with django 1.8. The console shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/adriann/django/project_varincenti/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 351, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/adriann/django/project_varincenti/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 343, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/adriann/django/project_varincenti/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 177, in fetch_command
    commands = get_commands()
  File "/home/adriann/django/project_varincenti/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 101, in wrapper
    result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/adriann/django/project_varincenti/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 72, in get_commands
    for app_config in reversed(list(apps.get_app_configs())):
  File "/home/adriann/django/project_varincenti/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 137, in get_app_configs
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/adriann/django/project_varincenti/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Comment: production or local?

Answer (score 4):

There are answers elsewhere on Stackoverflow about how this could be actually about app registry, but I believe it is more often just an indicator that something is wrong in the settings and Django didn't handle failure well.

I just had the exact same error by just having a bad logger filename in `LOGGING` settings -- the directory I was referring to did not exist, so logger initialisation failed.

Comment: Saved me, thanks!  This error is so misleading when all you're missing is a log dir specified in LOGGING!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using a Virtual Environment.

Perhaps you have an app included under `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`, but it isn't installed (e.g. via `pip install django-multisite`) in your virtual environment.

*(I received this same error after starting to use a Virtual Environment.)*

Comment: I too had this issue. Forgot to install an additional app in the virtual env when going from my local environment to the virtual machine..

Answer (score 1):

I actually had the same error today, which is strange as everything was working properly yesterday and I do not think I have changed anything. 
I got the error when trying to start up the dev server. I had recently upgraded this project to 1.8.

The solution for me was: I changed my PYTHONPATH on the startup script (to make sure it also points to the 1.8 version) of the dev server and everything seemed to work perfectly again.